# view not refreshed when $scope is updated inside $http

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-options

I have the following HTML:

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="inputSystemLoggingId" 
data-html="true" ng-init="initDataSources()" ng-options="a.id for a in systemLoggingIds" 
ng-model="systemLoggingId">
</select>
```

and the following Controller:

```
$scope.systemLoggingId = "4";
$scope.systemLoggingIds = [{"id":"4"}];

$scope.initDataSources = function() {

    $http({
        method: 'get',
        url: '/amenityLogging/getSystemLoggingIds'
    }).success(function (listSystemLoggingIds) {
        console.log($scope.systemLoggingIds);
        $scope.systemLoggingIds = [{"id":"5"}];
        $scope.systemLoggingId = "5";
        console.log($scope.systemLoggingIds);
        $('#inputSystemLoggingId').selectpicker();
    });
}
```

I see that my $scope.systemLoggingIds get correctly updated from 4 to 5, yet the view doesn't seems to get notified about the new values. If I move the code outside of the $http request, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Im guessing it's that jQuery plugin causing weirdness

Comment: seems like you might actually be right, investigating

Comment: Anything that happens inside jQuery happens outside the privy of Angular, if you use jQuery to change things you need to let Angular know about it by using `$scope.$apply()`

Comment: I see it more the other way around tho'? It seems like jQuery is not getting notified about the new Angular model? In any case, calling $scope.$apply() inside the $http request creates an error

Comment: The underline selection box is getting updated. See from http://jsfiddle.net/injulkarnilesh/6fmxmx8s/2/, if you comment  `$('#inputSystemLoggingId').selectpicker();` it works fine. This selectpicker is hiding the underline selection box and creating set of div, span and li all over it. Somehow it's now getting the updated values in selection box.